# Cordova cordova-plugin-googleplus Incremental scope

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, google-drive-api, gmail-api, google-plus-signin

Is there a way to request an incremental scope with this after the user is logged in with the basic profile scope?   Google openly encourages using incremental scope but there seems to be no way with a cordova app unless you request the full scope for the first time.